# Sony Ericsson Xperia X10 USB Debugging Detection Issues

Tags: usb-debugging, sony-ericsson-xperia-x10, flashtool

My PC - well, specifically, Flashtool - doesn't detect that my X10 has USB Debugging turned on, even though it displays that it has been activated both in the Settings menu and the notification shade. I've tried the modded Flashtool from XDA-Dev, and the latest versions, but to no avail. Any suggestions? I believe the drivers are up to date, as I can turn storage mode on when plugging it in and transfer files just fine. Rooted, running stock. It was fine pre-root, but as soon as I rooted it the first time around, it hasn't been able to detect. Recovery can't be flashed due to the lack of debugging.

Comment: Are you using windows 8

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate

Comment: Did u see any exclamation mark near the driver in device manager? Try different port or computer even try different cable

Comment: Does the led turn on when you connect? What error are you getting in flashtool when you are connecting?

Comment: That's the thing, no errors, no nothing. It can connect just fine, but it never detects that USB debugging is on...

Comment: What do you mean by connect fine. Can you provide a snapshot of device manager. Can you check with other pc or Settings > Xperia > USB Connectivity > USB connection mode and select Mass storage mode (MSC). Note that USB cable must be unplugged to change this option and then connect

Comment: Can you able to solve the problem

Comment: Yes, after a gazillion tries, constantly uninstalling and reinstalling PC Companion and Flashtool, and removing and installing the same drivers over and over again, it finally detected Debugging. Mass storage mode was selected the whole time. No clue what happened that caused it to suddenly start working, but I'm not complaining haha. Thanks for all of the help! It still only detects after I unplug and plug in the USB once or twice, but I can live with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `Sony Pc companion`.Go to folder in which flashtool is installed mostly `C:/Flashtool`.You will find Drivers folder in which you will find `Driver.exe` click it select the driver for your device click install.

Windows will give you error select `Trust the vendor`. It is better to turn off your antivirus.

Once installed enable usb debugging mode and connect

Comment: I've already done so. I used the drivers in Flashtool, as well as Sony PC Companion, but to no avail...do you think it might just be hardware?